# NoMethodError: undefined method 'login_path' in Ruby gem shopify_app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, shopify

I am using the Gem shopify_app (https://github.com/Shopify/shopify_app) to build an embedded Shopify app. In the file `login_protection.rb` there is this method:

```
def redirect_to_login
  session[:return_to] = request.fullpath if request.
  redirect_to login_path(shop: params[:shop])
end
```

I am getting the above error message, that `login_path` is not found. Since nobody else is complaining about this, I'm almost certain I am missing something very simple but I really am stuck. Does anybody have any pointers to help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that in version 5.0.1 or 5.0.2 (I was upgrading from 5.0.0) a named route called `login_route` was introduced. Usually apps have this route, either explicitly named or derived by Rails from the URL `/login`. I instead used `/shopify/login` as URL to my login page so my derived route name was `shopify_login` instead. All in all I've been looking in all the wrong places and didn't the forest for the trees so I was stuck. Just make sure this named route `login` exists and everything is good.

Answer (score 0):

Try running

```
    rake routes | grep login
```

This should tell you what paths you have defined that contain login in them. Otherwise just run rake routes and ensure that login_path, or whatever path you are looking for exists.

Also you may have a syntax error here:

```
    if request.
```

You are calling no method on request.

Comment: Thing is, this is used in the gem and I'm left wondering what to do with it now. Do I need to define it in my app? And what would the route contain? The path to the Shopify login page? What is the correct URL to use? It's something rather specific to Shopify (not Rails or routes in general). The demo app on Github doesn't have it defined either but it seems to work there. I'm confused :-)